# How do I start turtlebot_simulator correctly

Tags: ros, simulation, turtlebot, turtlebot-gazebo, turtlebot-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I installed ROS via:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu oneiric main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full
echo "source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
```

Then turtlebot via

```
sudo apt-get install ssh ros-electric-turtlebot-robot
```

However when I run the turtlebot simulator via:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch
```

I get

```
[turtlebot_gazebo] is not a package or launch file name
```

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31623/how-do-i-start-turtlebot_simulator-correctly/) by [c01e](https://answers.ros.org/users/1442/c01e/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The turtlebot-robot debian doesn't include the turtlebot_simulator package to install this package:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-turtlebot-simulator-desktop
```

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2012-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3